# How to move parts of a dynamic pivot table to a separate table?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have pivot table pulling data from a query from a proprietary database system we use at work. I'm trying to figure out a way to move certain parts of the pivot table to a different sheet where it wouldn't exist as a pivot table there. My problem I'm running into is that the table changes the number of columns and rows depending upon the types and amounts of things that we shipped that shift, so I can't have it simply have my new table equal the cell values in the pivot table.

[image]

This is an example of the pivot data having fewer columns and rows based on what occurred that shift at work.

[image]

The reason why I would like this in a regular table as opposed to a pivot table is because there's other calculations I'd like to put into the table that extend beyond a pivot table's capabilities (ex. have the user id be displayed as their name, and have a weighted system based off of what the driver moves, but I suppose that's irrelevant.)

I've been poking around the internet, and it seems that the majority of answers to this issue deal with static tables. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use combination of `VLOOKUP` and `HLOOKUP` or `MATCH` and `INDEX`.

Comment: You can copy the entire `PivotTable.Range` to another sheet, and then you'll have a regular `Range`. Or, you can loop through the `PivotItems` and find the value you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you want the cell to have the value from "BEER Total" for "M307577". Then this would be the formula you put in the cell:

```
=VLOOKUP("M307577",A5:Z100,MATCH("BEER Total",A5:Z5,0),FALSE)
```

`"A5:Z100"` would be the whole pivot table and `"A5:Z5"` would be the first row containing variables.

---

As you mentioned you are not familiar with VBA, I would suggest this approach:

Use the first column and first row of the second sheet as a reference. Refer to all the variables from the pivot table there (refer to the cell containing IDs and Variables, and pull the formula to the last row for IDs and last column for variables (or a reasonable range as last column and row would not be sufficient)). This will leave you with zeros, empty cells from the pivot table sheet, but will have all the names that you need.

Then refer to those cells and use the aforementioned formula (instead of names, use the cells that you just created).

Whenever the pivot table updates, those cells will be updated as well and you will see the values for the corresponding ID and Variable.

Comment: I think maybe I explained this poorly, but the names will not be in the same spots every time, and neither will the column names. This is where I am struggling with this.

Comment: @Lampoa I explicitly defined the names (i.e. `BEER Total` and `M307577`). But I guess you want to refer to them (like in cells) so you can expand the formula, right?

Comment: I think I'm confused. The name M307577 would only occur 1/3 of the time I run this problem, as they only work one every three shift, so I'm looking for a way that doesn't tie a specific alias to a cell, but something that looks at the number of rows/columns that exist in the pivot table once updated, and copies those to a non-pivot table.

Comment: @Lampoa I am working on it. The solution would be in defining a dynamic range.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the description to reflect an example where the pivot table would have less data depending on what occurred during a specific shift.

Comment: @Lampoa if you want to account for last row/column then VBA is needed. Otherwise, you can make refer to the names included in your pivot table in a column and a row of the other sheet and expand the formula till the end (some of them will be zeros as the cells in the pivot table are empty). Then you can refer to those cells and use the formula I provided. Personally, I advise using VBA.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I'm just super unfamiliar with VBA, I studied chemical engineering in school and we didn't learn any coding!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the GETPIVOTDATA function.  Determine what your logic will look like and click on the appropriate combination of cells.  Excel will automatically setup the GETPIVOTDATA function appropriately for you.

http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot06.html

Also, if the last used columns and last used rows are changing, you will probably need a Macro to help you with your task.

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    MsgBox LastRow
End Sub

Sub LastColumnInOneRow()
'Find the last used column in a Row: row 1 in this example
    Dim LastCol As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    MsgBox LastCol
End Sub
```

You can use a combination of functions to help you get the last used cell in a specific range.

https://exceljet.net/formula/address-of-last-cell-in-range

From there, I think you can figure out your next steps.

Post back with more information if you still have trouble with this, or start a new post if your question is answered.

Comment: I tried using that, but the problem is, the ID numbers aren't the same every time I update the table, and neither are the column headers. That's where I'm stuck with this.